# Left Rolling join with the nearest and anterior date

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, lubridate

I'd like to a left join an information by the nearest and anterior date of specific observations. I'll take as an example this dataset :

| ID | Date1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2010-09-12 |
| B | 2009-05-28 |
| C | 2008-04-16 |

The table to join informations is as follows:

```
  ID      Date1 Rating
1  A 2010-06-13      1
2  A 2010-10-03      7
3  B 2008-12-28      3
4  B 2009-06-28      5
5  C 2008-01-02     12
6  C 2008-05-23      6
```

The final Database I'd like to have will be :

| ID | Date1 | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2010-09-12 | 1 |
| B | 2009-05-28 | 3 |
| C | 2008-04-16 | 12 |

As displayed above, it is important to notice that I want the anterior date, even if the ulterior date is nearer than the anterior one.

I've tried to data.table rolling join but not sure it will take the anterior rating by date:

```
  test=df1[df2, roll = T]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## data.table

You were close:

- in `data.table` joins, the LHS table is on the *inside* of the bracket (as long as there is not join-assignment ... confusing, perhaps);

  - said differently, it might be easier to consider the `[`-bracket as a "right join", where using `dt2[dt1,...]`, the `dt1` is the primary, data joined *onto* `dt1`;
  - for clarity, though, in other cases when one wants to do an assignment join (e.g., `dt1[dt2, newval := i.otherval, on = .(id, quux)]`), that is in fact a left-join ... confusing, almost certainly.
- you need the `on=` clause.

```r
df2[df1, on = .(ID, Date1), roll = TRUE]
#        ID      Date1 Rating
#    <char>     <char>  <int>
# 1:      A 2010-09-12      1
# 2:      B 2009-05-28      3
# 3:      C 2008-04-16     12
```

Another way to look at this is to do an assignment join, which reverses the order of tables. One advantage to this is that it allows you to cherry-pick specific columns, including `df2$Date1`:

```r
df1[df2, c("Rating", "Date1.y") := .(i.Rating, i.Date1), on = .(ID, Date1), roll = -Inf]
#        ID      Date1 Rating    Date1.y
#    <char>     <char>  <int>     <char>
# 1:      A 2010-09-12      1 2010-06-13
# 2:      B 2009-05-28      3 2008-12-28
# 3:      C 2008-04-16     12 2008-01-02
```

Note the use of `roll = -Inf`. More can be read in [`?data.table`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html), though I confess that for me I tend to need to practice it on various frames to really see how to use it.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, join_by(ID, closest(Date1 >= Date1)),
            suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  select(-Date1.y)
#        ID      Date1 Rating
#    <char>     <char>  <int>
# 1:      A 2010-09-12      1
# 2:      B 2009-05-28      3
# 3:      C 2008-04-16     12
```

Since the rolling join here includes `Date1.x` and `Date1.y` as output columns, I could have gone without `suffix=` and instead finished with `select(ID, Date1=Date1.x, Rating)` (and any other real columns you have), but I think it's generally easier to force the suffix (keeping the LHS column name unchanged) and dropping the joined column. (Though it might be interesting for you to know which `df2$Date1` was used, over to you.)

Comment: Or `df1[ , Rating := df2[.SD, on = .(ID, Date1), roll = Inf, x.Rating]]`

Comment: What a great and complete answer ! Both data.table and dplyr methods worked on my dataset. Thanks a lot